# PHP nesting switch inside a foreach

Tags: php, foreach, switch-statement

Working on a website for a game I play.  On this page a user can upload a block of text describing a piece of equipment and hopefully I can parse through it an create an object and upload it to MySQL.  Here is an example block:

```
Item:         an ethereal bracelet
Key words:    geq grey_man man ethereal bracelet geq_Guxx
Type:         treasure
Level:        50
Extra flags:  rot-death no-transfer
Weight:       2
Value:        0
Affects:      spell-resistance by 5.
Affects:      dexterity by 1.
Affects:      strength by 1.
Affects:      intelligence by 1.
Affects:      wisdom by 1.
Affects:      hitroll by 5.
Affects:      constitution by 1.
Affects:      hp by 50.
Affects:      damroll by 10.
```

And here is the function inside my equipment class:

```
public function create_eq_from_text($text) {
        $text = trim($_POST['item']);
        $text = explode("\n", $text);
        foreach($text as $line) {
            switch($line) {
                case strstr($line, 'Item:'):
                    $this->name = trim(str_replace('Item:', '', $line));
                    break;
            case strstr($line, 'Key words:'):
                $line = trim(str_replace('Key words:', '', $line));
                $this->key_words = $line;
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'Type:'):
                $line = trim(str_replace('Type:', '', $line));
                $this->type = $line;
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'Level:'):
                $line = trim(str_replace('Level:', '', $line));
                $this->level = intval($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'Extra flags:'):
                $line = trim(str_replace('Extra flags:', '', $line));
                $this->extra_flags = $line;
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'Weight:'):
                $line = trim(str_replace('Weight:', '', $line));
                $this->weight = intval($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'Value:'):
                $line = trim(str_replace('Value:', '', $line));
                $this->value = intval($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'physical attacks'):
                $this->p_ac = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'magic attacks'):
                $this->m_ac = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'spell-resistance'):
                $this->saves = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'dexterity by'):
                $this->dex = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'strength by'):
                $this->str = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'intelligence by'):
                $this->intel = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'wisdom by'):
                $this->wis = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'constitution by'):
                $this->con = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'damroll by'):
                $this->dam = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'hitroll by'):
                $this->hit = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'hp by'):
                $this->hp = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'mana by'):
                $this->mana = get_number($line);
                break;
            case strstr($line, 'Damage is'):
                $line = trim(str_replace('Damage is', '', $line));
                $line = str_replace('.', '', $line);
                $this->weapon_damage = $line;
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Here is the form's code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['item'])) {
    $item = new Equipment;
    $item->create_eq_from_text($item);
    print_r($item);
    }
```

For some reason the only thing the switch is catching is the strstr('Item:').  First I thought the break in the switch was breaking out of the foreach, but I have ruled that out.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: For a case to be evaluated it must match the arg passed into switch.

Comment: @Matthew Scragg strstr() will return false if there is not a match, and the odd thing is that it works for setting the $this->name but doesn't fire on anything else.

Comment: You'll have to restructure that... with a switch statement you are basically saying "here's a value $line, compare to all these case values and run wherever there's a match". And naturally $line != strstr($line, 'Item:')

Comment: basically whats happening for the first line in if/else equivalent is: if ("Item:         an ethereal bracelet" == strstr($line, 'Item:')){ $this->name = trim(str_replace('Item:', '', $line)); }

Comment: use multiple `if` statements and `strpos`

Comment: Yeah I completely misinterpreted what strstr did, looking for a string_contains.  Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use switch statement for such a case because you're looking for a substring inside $line. Switch statement looks for a match with the given variable, not a boolean value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can match a switch with a boolean in php

Comment: you misinterpret my statement, what I mean is a match between the variable in switch (say a string) with the case (a boolean value)